# One dimensional linear maps are scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to prove that if $T: \mathbb F \to \mathbb F$ is linear where $\mathbb F \in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C \}$ then $Tv = \lambda v$ for some scalar. It occurred to me that one may prove this claim by first proving that there is a bijection from the set of linear maps $V \to W$ where $V,W$ are finite dimensional to the set of $n\times m$ matrices. But this is more general and I'm wondering if there is a short neat proof for the specific case $n=m=1$?

Comment: A linear map in uniquely determined by its image on a basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$T$ is linear $\implies$ $Tx=T(x \cdot 1)=x \cdot T(1)=\lambda x$.

Comment: More abstractly, let $T : V \to V$ for $V$ a $1$-dimensional $F$-vector space. Let $0 \neq v_0 \in V$, so that $\{v_0\}$ is a basis for $V$, and hence, in particular, $T v_0 = \lambda v_0$ for some $\lambda \in F$. Then, for any $v = \alpha v_0 \in V$, 
$$
 Tv = T(\alpha v_0) = \alpha T(v_0) = \alpha (\lambda v_0) = \lambda (\alpha v_0) = \lambda v,
$$
so that $T = \lambda \operatorname{Id}_V$, as required. Note that the result is entirely coordinate-independent, even though the proof does require a choice of basis.