# Understanding proof of 1-Dimension Vector space is multiplication by scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

This problem is from the book Linear Algebra Done Right. The question is :

> If $T: \mathbb F \to \mathbb F$ is linear where $\mathbb F \in
>  \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C \}$ then $Tv = \lambda v$ for some scalar.

One solution given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463495/one-dimensional-linear-maps-are-scalar-multiplication) post is the following:

> Let $T:V \to V$ for V a 1-dimensional F-vector space. Let $0 \neq v_0
> \epsilon V$, so that $\{v_0\}$ is a basis for V, and hence, in
> particular, $Tv_0=\lambda v_0$ for some $\lambda \in F$. Then,
> for any $v = \alpha v_0 \in V$,$$Tv=T(\alpha v_0)=\alpha
> T(v_0)=\alpha(\lambda v_0)=\lambda(\alpha v_0)=\lambda v,$$so that
> $T=\lambda\operatorname{Id}|_V$, as required. Note that the result is entirely
> coordinate-independent, even though the proof does require a choice of
> basis.

My question is, how this "$Tv_0=\lambda v_0$" step is coming? And if this step is true, then why we are doing rest of the prove?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $V$ is $1$-dimensional, then every vector is a multiple of every non-zero vector. So, either $v_0=0$, in which case $T(v_0)=0=\lambda v_0$ for *every* scalar $\lambda$, or $v_0\ne0$, in which case $T(v_0)$ is a multiple of $v_0$.

But this only proves that, for **a** vector $v_0$, there is some $\lambda$ such that the equality $T(v_0)=\lambda v_0$ holds for **that** $v_0$. It still remains to be proved that there is some scalar $\lambda$ such that you have $T(v)=\lambda$ for *every* vector $v$.

Comment: Thanks Jose! Yours and Fred answers together helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

We have $Tv_0 \in V= span\{v_0\}$, thus there is a scalar $ \lambda$ such that $Tv_0= \lambda v_0.$